# Gradle 3.0 BuildException cannot create directory

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, gradle

I'm on windows and updated to Android Studio (AS) 3.0 RC1. When I try to built our project with gradle via AS or terminal it stops, the Stacktrace is at the end. The weird part is, that on my colleagues Mac it just builts.

So I'm guessing something is wrong with the path. I couldn't find anything specific about this BuildException. Anyone has any idea why the path looks duplicated? `C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug\C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug`

What else can I try to fix this? I cleaned, rebuilt and restarted everything I could.

**Update** I just updated AS to 3.0 RC 2 and still get the same problem.

**Update** Same happens with the stable AS 3.0 Release :(

```
>FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageTestDebug'.
> Cannot create directory C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug\C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageTestDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Cannot create directory C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug\C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(OutputScope.java:241)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:236)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:197)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:181)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:471)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create directory C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug\C:\Development\Workspace\Project\app\build\outputs\apk\Test\debug
at com.android.utils.FileUtils.mkdirs(FileUtils.java:215)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:664)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:522)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(OutputScope.java:186)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(OutputScope.java:203)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$null$8(OutputScope.java:225)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With the stable release of Android Studio 3.0 I digged a little deeper. Turns out our script for naming the APK didn't work, but was only breaking on Windows.

Old Script:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def fileName = outputFile.name.replace('.apk', "-${versionName}.apk")
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

Fixed Script:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to change the default output directory it?

Comment: i tried this solution but its not working need help here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241450/android-studio-3-0-1-error-in-build-gradle

Answer (score 1):

In your gradle file (module level), are you using applicationVariants to rename your apk or things like this ?
I had to remove this part in my gradle file to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am building same app with Android Studio 3.0 on both Linux or Windows.
After upgrading to Gradle 3.0.1, I had a similar issue on Windows, while it was working fine on Linux:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':smsreminder:packageDebug'.
>   > Cannot create directory C:\Users\Florent\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\myapp\build\outputs\apk\debug\C:\Users\Florent\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\myapp\build\outputs\apk\debug

And thanks to above answer from Leo, I made this more friendly apk name:

```
outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
=> produces: debug-x.y.apk

outputFileName = output.outputFile.name + ".${variant.versionName}.apk"
=> produces: MyAppName.x.y.apk
```

Otherwise, I found this working too if one want to keep default :

```
if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows)
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        else
            outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, outputFileName.replace(output.outputFile.name, defaultConfig.applicationId + ".apk"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  variant.outputs.all {
      outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
```

This code will fix the issue.!! There is a minor change to the above answer in this script

Comment: and in gradle version 3.1.0 ?