# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was using the following code in my gradle script to rename the apks generated with AndroidStudio:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, defaultConfig.versionCode + "_" + output.outputFile.name)
    }
}
```

So it was generating apks with names like: **345-app-release.apk**, where 345 is the versionCode.

But after updating to AndroidStudio 3.0 it returns the following error:

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for
>   ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug,
>   filters=[]}} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.

How can I achieve a similar renaming with the new build tools.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use `output.outputFileName` instead of `output.outputFile`

Comment: It was created error afterwards, I needed to solve it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959050/2061089

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949311/cannot-set-the-value-of-read-only-property-outputfile-for-apkvariantoutputimpl/50464200#50464200

Comment: This causes an error: **ERROR: No such property: parent for class: java.lang.String**

Answer (score 32):

## 2019 - Simple Solution for Gradle 3.0+** and 3.1.0

To change the name of the APK in Android

```
 android { //add inside the android {}
   ......
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.outputs.all {
           def flavor = variant.name
           def versionName = variant.versionName
           outputFileName = "prefix_${flavor}_${versionName}.apk"
       }
   }
}
```

> prefix_release_1.0.1.apk

Comment: Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name

getting this error

Comment: @Keselme  I lower down the gradle tools version in top level build.gradle file.

Comment: this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949311/cannot-set-the-value-of-read-only-property-outputfile-for-apkvariantoutputimpl/50464200#50464200

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Comment: @MeLine try now.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked! Upvoted

Answer (score 17):

Try this code :

```
buildTypes {

       applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def name = "myapp_v${variant.versionName}(${variant.versionCode}).apk"
                output.outputFileName = name
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

> **In or After gradle 3.1.0**

try below code

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = new File(
                    "release_build", // here you can change the name
                    output.outputFile.name)
        }
}
```

Comment: I got this error Could not set unknown property 'outputFileName' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I resolved it by just refusing to update to Gradle 4.4 (in my case).So when Studio asks (when you open your project for the first time) you to update Gradle to support instant run,etc just simply refuse and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to
1. change **each** to "all"
2. change **output.outputFile** to "outputFileName"
3. Run **$./gradlew clean build** in terminal

For example, if your artifacts.gradle settings were this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def finalVersionCode = 10000 + versionCode
    output.versionCodeOverride = finalVersionCode
    output.outputFile = new File(
         output.outputFile.parent,       output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk","-${finalVersion}.apk"))
}
```

}

Then you would want to **change it to this:**

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

variant.outputs.all { output ->
    def finalVersionCode = 10000 + versionCode
    output.versionCodeOverride = finalVersionCode
    outputFileName = new File(
         output.outputFile.parent,
         outputFileName.replace(".apk", "-${finalVersionCode}.apk"))
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

change your code into:-

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "${variant.applicationId}-${variant.versionName}.apk")
    }
}
```