# Gradle Version 4.6 - Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am a newbie to Android. So as part of my learning I was following this tutorial to make an icon pack - https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-create-an-android-icon-pack-app-ecb77811b938

When I imported the project to Android Studio, I got the following error - [Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949311/cannot-set-the-value-of-read-only-property-outputfile-for-apkvariantoutputimpl)
I solved that error as the answer was already mentioned there. After that when I tried to build the project I got the following error - Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name.

When I opened the file in Android Studio, it showed that the error was occuring in the following code:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFileName = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent, "MyIconPack-${variant.versionName}.apk")
    }
}
```

So I searched here again and found this - [android studio 3.1: build:gradle:3.1.0 - Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530142/android-studio-3-1-buildgradle3-1-0-absolute-path-are-not-supported-when-se), but I was unable to understand the answer for that question.

So please help me to solve the error.

Comment: the title of the question does not match the example code provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works alike this with later version of Gradle:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def fileName = "${project.name}_${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName).getName()
    }
}
```

because `output.outputFileName` is (or had become) a read-only property.

Comment: it gives new error as Could not set unknown property 'outputFileName' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Comment: @VatsalDesai Use `output.outputFileName` instead of just `outputFileName`.