# Android Studio 3.2 - Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following a tutorial to develop icon pack for android and when I imported the project I got several errors and it was solved here - [Gradle Version 4.6 - Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523902/gradle-version-4-6-absolute-path-are-not-supported-when-setting-an-output-file)

After solving that error, the following error poped up.

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971.
Searched in the following locations:

file:/C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom

file:/C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar

file:/C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom

file:/C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar

file:/C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom

file:/C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar

https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom

https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :licensing
```

I tried to open the URLs and I was able to download JAR (aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar) and JSON (aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom.json) files from the first 2 URLs. Should I copy these files somewhere? What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65195608/6401241

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Most likely you do not have the Google repository in your project's build.gradle file. Add `google()` in BOTH locations as shown below:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after adding google() in the build.gradle file.

Comment: @TomJ Did you add `google()' in BOTH of the spots above? Notice that it is present in two locations...

Comment: Looks like a gradle upgrade to 4.6 misses `google()` in ``allprojects { /** */ }`` section. This works!

Comment: Perfect Solution...Thanks...
BTW...where you found this type of solution.. :D

Comment: @Neo You know, at this point I don't recall how I became aware of this solution. Probably trial and error.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve the issue by adding google() in both locations:

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> *Now add "**, google()**" in

> Android Plugin Repository

and

> Default Library Repository

*

Answer (score 8):

When you upgrade to 4.6 version of gradle. You need following upgrades too. [Gradle Plugin Release page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

#### 1. Android Studio 3.+

You need Android Studio version 3.+ to have 4.6 version of gradle. At the time of post latest release was 3.2.1. You can see latest release on [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/).

#### 2. Gradle Plugin 3.1.+

You need 3.1.+ gradle plugin for gradle-4.6 support. Check in project level **build.gradle**.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

At the time of post latest version was 3.2.1. You can see [latest release here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

#### 3. Add Google Maven Library

You need to add Google Maven library to project level build.gradle like below code.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see the dependencies of module `:licensing` and use `com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0` (or even `"com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0:windows"`) there, which is the final version ...that `4818971` version should ordinary come with an `alpha` prefix/suffix (the version number seems to be incorrect). maybe adding repository `google()` might be required, too. ordinary, that dependency should be present; removing that dependency might be another possible option.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a little more? I am a newbie to android, so I will be a little bit disturbing to you.

Comment: @TomJ just yesterday updated the same dependency: https://github.com/google/bundletool/compare/master...syslogic:master#diff-c197962302397baf3a4cc36463dce5ea

Answer (score 1):

For those people who still face exactly the same problem even after adding two *google* to **BOTH** positions in relevant gradle file.I would suggest you to check `Android Studio -> Preferences -> HTTP Proxy` page.
If you find it says some warnings like "...have set JVM proxy to 127.0.0.1".Then you should consider vpn-related issues which depends on your context.
If your desktop is MacOS, then go to `Network` setting page, `advance->proxy` tab,**uncheck** all the checkbox there.
Back to your IDE as following steps: `Android Studio->File->Invalidate Caches/Restart`.After that,go back to check `Android Studio -> Preferences -> HTTP Proxy` page again,previous warnings should be gone.Run again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by upgrading my classpath from

```
    'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0
```

to

```
    'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

hope this helps