# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/ide/common/res2/ResourceSet after updating android studio to 3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Today I updated my android studio to 3.2 and when I am trying to build the `gradle`. I am getting below error. Please can someone help me on this.

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/ide/common/res2/ResourceSet
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:185)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$3.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:172)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$3.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandlerKt$sam$Action$449ec8ff.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.applyExperimental(AndroidSubplugin.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(KotlinPlugin.kt:772)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.access$processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:455)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:525)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:455)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandlerKt$sam$Action$449ec8ff.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:524)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:455)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    ... 92 more
```

This is my build.gradle(app module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.saga.yoyo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 11
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.2'
    glideLibraryVersion = '4.6.1'
    retrofitLibraryVersion = '2.4.0'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    //Glide library
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideLibraryVersion"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideLibraryVersion"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitLibraryVersion"
    //RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"
    //ObjectBox
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:$objectboxVersion"
    kapt "io.objectbox:objectbox-processor:$objectboxVersion"
    //MaterialDialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    //ReactiveNetwork
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:0.12.3'
    //MultiDex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //Fotoapparat
    implementation 'io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:library:2.2.0'
    //ChartView
    implementation 'com.github.razerdp:AnimatedPieView:1.2.4'

    implementation "com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:2.0.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'me.shaohui.advancedluban:library:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This is my build.gradle(project module):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    ext.objectboxVersion = '1.4.3'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541525/android-studio-3-2-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-4818971/52542837#52542837

Comment: `google()` is there in my project module. That is not the issue. @NileshRathod

Comment: share your project Build gradle with question

Comment: Updated the question with `build.gradle`(project module).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541861/7666442

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your Kotlin version is quite old.

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

I think you will need to update it to newer version like:

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'

Then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by navigating to "Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates" in the menu bar (Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates), and then installing the latest available version.