# Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/Users/delevinying/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/Users/delevinying/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
file:/Users/delevinying/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/Users/delevinying/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
file:/Users/delevinying/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/Users/delevinying/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
Required by:project :app
```

Comment: Seems issue with gradle sync. Similar question is been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541525/android-studio-3-2-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-4818971

Answer (score 1):

I just solved mine by adding `google()` to both the repositories

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```