# WSO2 : Rebuild the Android agent application

Tags: android, wso2

When I try to rebuild agent, like said at point 4.b here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Integrating+the+Android+System+Service+Application#IntegratingtheAndroidSystemServiceApplication-Operationssupportedviathesystemserviceapplication

I get this kind of errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':client@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :iDPProxy.
Could not resolve project :iDPProxy.
Required by:
project :client
Project :client declares a dependency from configuration 'releaseCompile' to configuration 'release' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :iDPProxy.
```

Here's the java code (build.gradle):

```
  releaseCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'release')
  stagingCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'staging')
  standaloneCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'standalone')
  debugCopeCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'debug')
  debugCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'debug')
```

Project idpproxy is here

[image]

Thanks for help. Regards.

**EDIT :**

I've done something but i don't know if it's correct. I'm in android studio 3.0. In build.gradle:

```
    implementation project(':iDPProxy')
//releaseCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'release')
//stagingCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'staging')
//standaloneCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'standalone')
//debugCopeCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'debug')
//debugCompile project(path: ':iDPProxy', configuration: 'debug')
```

and i've commented all debugcope lines, like this :

```
     /* debugCope {
        // DEBUG_MODE_ENABLED: Make the agent print the debug logs.
        // Make this false in production.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_MODE_ENABLED", "true"
        // ALLOW_SYSTEM_APPS_IN_APPS_LIST_RESPONSE: Setting this to true will make the
        // App list response to the service to include system apps as well.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_SYSTEM_APPS_IN_APPS_LIST_RESPONSE", "false"
        // Protocol used to communicate with the server. Valid values are http:// or https://
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_PROTOCOL", "\"http://\""
        buildConfigField "String", "API_SERVER_PORT", "\"80\""
        //API version that supported by the server
        buildConfigField "float", "SERVER_API_VERSION", "1.0f"
        // Set DEFAULT_OWNERSHIP to null if no overriding is needed. Other possible values are,
        // BYOD or COPE. If you are using the mutual SSL authentication
        // This value must be set to a value other than null.
        buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_OWNERSHIP", "\"COPE\""
        //DEFAULT_HOST - Hardcode the server host to avoid having the user type it during
        //enrollment. If the user must type the hostname/IP during enrollment, leave it as null.
        buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_HOST", "null"
        // APP_MANAGER_HOST: If the App store host is different from the DEFAULT_HOST
        // change this value.
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_MANAGER_HOST", "null"
        // CLOUD_MANAGER: If the App is pointed to cloud use cloud management host to resolve
        // tenants of user. Otherwise set this to null
        buildConfigField "String", "CLOUD_MANAGER", "null"
        // SIGN_UP_URL: Set self registration link to sign up
        buildConfigField "String", "SIGN_UP_URL", "null"
        // AGENT_PACKAGE: If a modification of the agent's package name is done, this must be
        // altered
        buildConfigField "String", "AGENT_PACKAGE", "\"org.wso2.iot.agent\""
        // FIRMWARE_UPGRADE_RETRY_COUNT: How many time the agent must retry if firmware upgrade
        // fails.
        buildConfigField "int", "FIRMWARE_UPGRADE_RETRY_COUNT", "5"
        // CATALOG_APP_PACKAGE_NAME: If a modification of the catalog apps's package
        // name is done, this must be altered.
        buildConfigField "String", "CATALOG_APP_PACKAGE_NAME", "\"org.wso2.app.catalog\""
        // System service specific configurations.
        // SYSTEM_APP_ENABLED: This is to set if the system app will also be installed.
        // If this is set org.wso2.emm.system.service must also be available in the device.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SYSTEM_APP_ENABLED", "true"
        // SYSTEM_SERVICE_PACKAGE: If system service app is in use, the package name of it is
        // defined here so that the agent knows the package name of the system service to
        // contact.
        buildConfigField "String", "SYSTEM_SERVICE_PACKAGE", "\"org.wso2.iot.system.service\""
        // HIDE_UNREGISTER_BUTTON: Hide the unregister button after enrollment so that  the
        // unenrollment can only be done remotely.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "HIDE_UNREGISTER_BUTTON", "false"
        // Auto enrollment specific configurations
        // AUTO_ENROLLMENT_BACKGROUND_SERVICE_ENABLED: This is to specify if the enrollment
        // will be done in a background service. This is typically related to mutual SSL based
        // enrollments only.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "AUTO_ENROLLMENT_BACKGROUND_SERVICE_ENABLED", "false"
        // SKIP_LICENSE: Skip displaying the license policy during enrollment.
        // This is recommended to be used in conjunction with
        // AUTO_ENROLLMENT_BACKGROUND_SERVICE_ENABLED
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SKIP_LICENSE", "true"
        // HIDE_LOGIN_UI: Skip displaying the login screen during enrollment.
        // This is recommended to be used in conjunction with
        // AUTO_ENROLLMENT_BACKGROUND_SERVICE_ENABLED
        buildConfigField "boolean", "HIDE_LOGIN_UI", "false"
        // SKIP_WORK_PROFILE_CREATION: This will hide the work profile creation step from the
        // user. This is recommended to be used in conjunction with
        // AUTO_ENROLLMENT_BACKGROUND_SERVICE_ENABLED
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SKIP_WORK_PROFILE_CREATION", "true"
        // HIDE_ERROR_DIALOG: If this is set to true, agent will not show any error messages.
        // This is only recommended to use when the enrollment happens in background, and no
        // user interaction is needed. i.e in conjunction with
        // AUTO_ENROLLMENT_BACKGROUND_SERVICE_ENABLED
        buildConfigField "boolean", "HIDE_ERROR_DIALOG", "false"
        //Data publishing related configurations.
        // LOG_PUBLISHER_IN_USE: By default DAS_PUBLISHER or SPLUNK_PUBLISHER are the allowed
        // values. This specifies the log publisher to be used. This can be extended to write
        // custom publishers.
        buildConfigField "String", "LOG_PUBLISHER_IN_USE", "\"<SET_PUBLISHER>\""
        // LOG_LEVEL: When publishing log cat output to server, the log level tobe used.
        buildConfigField "String", "LOG_LEVEL", "\"*:W\""
        // NUMBER_OF_LOG_LINES: Number of log lines to be sent.
        buildConfigField "int", "NUMBER_OF_LOG_LINES", "500"
        //Splunk related configurations
        buildConfigField "String", "SPLUNK_API_KEY", "\"<SET_PUBLISHER>\""
        // HEC_TOKEN: Allowed values are MINT or HTTP
        buildConfigField "String", "SPLUNK_DATA_COLLECTOR_TYPE", "\"MINT\""
        buildConfigField "String", "HEC_TOKEN", "\"<SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN>\""
        buildConfigField "String", "HEC_MINT_ENDPOINT_URL", "\"<SPLUNK_HEC_MINT_ENDPOINT_URL>\""
        //Event publishing related configurations.
        // If set to true, registered events will be published to DAS. There are two event
        // publisher available by default and custom event types can be written and publihed
        // with the provided extension points.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "EVENT_LISTENING_ENABLED", "false"
        // Listening to application state changes such as an app getting installed, uninstalled,
        // upgraded and data cleared. If set to true, events will be published.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "APPLICATION_STATE_LISTENER", "false"
        // This is to listen to Runtime information such as CPU. If set to true,
        // events will be published.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "RUNTIME_STATE_LISTENER", "false"
        // The time the alarm should first go off, in milliseconds. The default value is 1000.
        buildConfigField "long", "DEFAULT_START_TIME", "1000"
        // The interval between subsequent repeats of the alarm, in milliseconds.
        // The default value is 30000.
        buildConfigField "long", "DEFAULT_INTERVAL", "30000"
        buildConfigField "int", "DEFAULT_LISTENER_CODE", "10001"
        // COSU related configurations.
        // ALLOW_MULTIPLE_APPS_IN_COSU_MODE: Set to true to make all installed app in COSU mode
        // accessible; if false only the last installation will be accessible.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_MULTIPLE_APPS_IN_COSU_MODE", "false"
        // By enabling this button, data wipe can be performed on a device without having to
        // issue a remote wipe operation.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DISPLAY_WIPE_DEVICE_BUTTON", "true"
        // Under COSU mode, this will enable an area in the screen to exit from screen pinned
        // mode. This MUST be set to false in production, if COSU is used.
        buildConfigField "boolean", "COSU_SECRET_EXIT", "false"
        buildConfigField "String", "EULA_TITLE", "\"POLICY AGREEMENT\""
        //Minimum Server API version that supported by the agent app
        buildConfigField "float", "MIN_SERVER_API_VERSION", "1.0f"
        //Maximum Server API version that supported by the agent app
        buildConfigField "float", "MAX_SERVER_API_VERSION", "1.0f"
        //Show notification to enable location if it is disabled
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ASK_TO_ENABLE_LOCATION", "false"
        //Publish location changes to server
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOCATION_PUBLISHING_ENABLED", "false"
        //Collect WiFi scan results
        buildConfigField "boolean", "WIFI_SCANNING_ENABLED", "true"
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    } */
```

And now, i get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':client:packageDebug'.
Cannot create directory C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\client\client\build\outputs\apk\debug\C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\client\client\build\outputs\apk\debug\C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\client\client\build\outputs\apk\debug
```

I don't know why the path is duplicated.

Invalidate cache and restart.

Now, i get this error at build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':client:mockableAndroidJar'.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:         java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In compiler command-line options, i've added this :

```
-x :client:mockableAndroidJar -x :idPProxy:mockableAndroidJar
```

I dont' know if it's correct. Now error is the same than above

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':client:packageDebug'.
Cannot create directory C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\client\client\build\outputs\apk\debug\C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\client\client\build\outputs\apk\debug\C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\client\client\build\outputs\apk\debug
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found. in fact, it seems that the sources are not coded for Windows and android studio 3.0.

Solution here : [Gradle 3.0 BuildException cannot create directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829395/gradle-3-0-buildexception-cannot-create-directory)

Change in build.gradle.

Thanks.